# How to get absolute value in xslt-1.0

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

Is there a way I can get the absolute value of a number in xslt-1.0?
abs() function works but in xslt-2.0.

But I need a way the same abs() functionality but for xslt-1.0

e.g => input -1.5, expected output 1.5

Any advise would be much appreciated.

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat('-', abs(salesPrice/ns2:BelopFelt))"/>
```

possibly something to replace abs(salesPrice/ns2:BelopFelt)

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
translate($input, '-', '')
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
(2*($input > 0) - 1)*$input
```

---

Note that some XSLT 1.0 processors support the [EXSLT `math:abs()` extension function](http://exslt.org/math/functions/abs/index.html).

Comment: unfortunately no luck with math:abs(). But translate is ok. It returns a string right. So is there any way i can convert it back to a double may be

Comment: <xsl:value-of select="concat('-', abs(abs(sumDiscountedPrice/ns2:BelopFelt) - abs(sumDiscountedPriceExVat/ns2:BelopFelt)))"/> 

something that might help in this scenario since I need the difference and concatenate minus after the calculation

Comment: In XSLT 1.0, data types are converted implicitly. For example: `<xsl:value-of select="translate(-5, '-', '') + 3" />` returns "5". (And there is no *double* data type.) Also, there is no need to concatenate a minus sign to convert a value to negative: use simply `-$yourValue`.

Comment: You are correct. This solved the issue. Many thanks for your help. Really appreciate it